# Certain $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $\mathbb{C}(u,v,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, involutions

Let $\beta$ be the following involution on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (= an automorphism of order two):
$\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

Let $s_1,s_2 \in S_{\beta}$ and $k \in K_{\beta}$.

Assume that the following conditions are satisfied:

**(1)** $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_1,k)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

**(2)** $s_1,s_2$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.

My revised question:

> Could one find an additional ('weak') condition that will guarantee that
>   $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$?

Please notice that my original question was:
"Is it true that $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$?" (See older edits).

**An attempt to answer:**
Take $s_1=x, s_2=y^4, k=xy$.
Perhaps a plausible additional condition that will guarantee that 
$\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$ is:
$y \notin \mathbb{C}(s_i,k)$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.

I have asked the above question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345126/certain-u-v-w-in-mathbbcx-y-such-that-mathbbcu-v-w-mathbbcx-y).

Thank you very much!

Comment: What about $s_1=s_2=x$ and $k=y$ ?

Comment: @Carot, thank you for your nice comment. Actually, I had in mind algebraically independent $s_1,s_2$. I apologize for not mentioning this.

Comment: Ok then what about $k=y$ and $s_1=x$ and $s_2=y^4$ ?

Comment: @Carot, nice, thank you very much. Please, do you think that there exists an additional mild condition that guarantees a positive answer to my question?

Comment: Well as long as I can take $k=y$, no. And I don't see a very convincing condition excluding this (and similar) case(s).

Comment: @Carot, I see, thank you.

Comment: @Carot, please, do you think that the following additional condition guarantees that $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x,y^2)$? The  additional condition is: $y \notin \mathbb{C}(s_i,k)$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.